# Replace a fragment from other activity than the host

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a MainActivity with a container FrameLayout in which I change multiple Fragments (Fragment A, Fragment B etc).

In one of this fragments let's say Fragment A I have to open another activity (Activity X).

The problem is that from this activity when I press a button I have to change Fragment A with Fragment B (in the background somehow) and after that, slideout Activity X (with translate animation), and slidein Fragment B ,all this without restarting the MainActivity because I have to keep the state.

How can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android uses loosely coupled components as its main building blocks. As you know, Activities are one of the main Android building blocks. Thus, interacting between activities are very restricted to a few ways.

- Passing data via Intents by `startActivity()`, `startActivityForResult()` etc. This way is useful whenever you are starting new activities.
- Sending broadcast Intents. This could be useful once you want to send a signal to your another app's component.
- Utilizing shared `Application` object.
- Java static fields and some other ways.

In your case I would recommend you to use a Dialog Fragment instead of your second activity, if your second activity is just a login activity or something like that.

---

**UPDATE #1:**

If you really would like to keep your second activity, so I would personally recommend using local broadcast mechanism.

Also there are another way to get this done. You could start your second activity as `startActivityForResult` and then whenever user gets back from your second activity to your first one, your first activity can get informed by its `onActivityResult` method. There you could switch those fragments.

Comment: In my case Fragment A is a list of products and when I click one product I open Activity X which is the product detail page. In the Fragment A I have the navigation drawer icon but in the Activity X i don't have it that's why i opted for an activity. How should I approach this so I can go from product detail to other fragment and not the products list?

Comment: Thank you for your help @abforce . I think I will make it the easy way around :) I will stick with the fragment implementation even for the product info and just replace the menu icon with an arrow. This way I keep my MainActivity active and I can change the fragments easily. I thought there was a easier way that I didn't know about but I was wrong. Thanks